# Git pull request for sub-branch

Tags: git

I was hoping to get some help with the following Git question:

I've a parent branch out of which I created Branch A. Later I extended Branch A by creating Branch B.

Am I correct in thinking that for my pull request for Branch B I should use the parent branch as my destination branch and not Branch A?

Comment: It depends where you want your changes to go!